# Json.NET Serializing Run throws StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, json.net, stack-overflow

I'm trying to serialize a `System.Windows.Documents.Run` object, and JsonConvert.SerializeObject() throws a StackOverflowException, even with ReferenceLoopHandling set to Ignore. What do I do in order to serialize a Run object?

Triggering Line:

```
string test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Run("testing"), 
    new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
try
{
var _run = new Run()
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//serialize your erorr
}
finally
{
//impossible but still
if (_run != null)
{
//serialize _run
}
}
```

If you object fails to created you cannot serialize null object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying my Run is null?

Comment: object fails to be created (new) -> threw error at constructing